# Lock md-sidenav in function

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, sidebar

I want to open right side nav in angular in a function and then keep it open unless an event such as a button click occurs. Right now i can open it in a function but a click on body area closes the side nav. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a Codepen or Plunkr with your code ?

Comment: I don't have it set up right now, might take me some time. The <md-sidenav> that comes with angular material. I can keep it open using md-islocked open but initially want it to be closed and only open and close from my function. When it is open it can be closed by clicking on backdrop, but I dont want this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before asking any solution you should refer the documentation and research a bit.

You should make use `$mdMedia('gt-md')` to lock it open for smaller devices and  `md-is-locked-open` attribute provided for `md-sidenav` directive.
As provided in the [API documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav)

Here is the solution that worked for me :

View :

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="isLeftOpen() &&  $mdMedia('gt-md')">
```

Controller :

```
$scope.isLeftOpen = function () {
  return $mdSidenav('left').isOpen();
}
```

Here is the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/wGPmwr) .

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my life. Can i ask another question here?

Comment: What is it about ?

Comment: It's about streaming services like soundcloud. I already posted a question about it but haven't received a satisfying answer. I will hugely appreciate thanks.

Comment: So can you answer that please?

Comment: Where's the question ?

Comment: I think the question has been removed. In HTML 5 we can use the audio tag to play audio on web sites. But that can be easily downloaded by inspecting the source or right clicking on the audio. I inspected soundcloud's source but there was no audio tag. How do these streaming sites operate? Do they use their custom players built entirely for them? How to build one?

Comment: I would hugely appreciate this. This has troubled me for a long time. Thank you so very much :-)

Comment: So can you answer my question please?